# Identifying specific characters in string (why is my code not working?)

Tags: javascript, string, loops

so I'm trying to work with searching through strings in JavaScript and my code looks like this:

```
var countChar = function(n) {

    let checkPhrase = n;
    for (let i = 0; i < (checkPhrase.length); i++) {
        if ((checkPhrase.indexOf("_") > -1) == true) {
            console.log(checkPhrase[i])
      }
  };
};

countChar("_.");
```

When I run the code the output is "_" and "."
Why? my if-statement can only be true when the index of checkPhrase === 0

Comment: `checkPhrase.indexOf("_")` is always `0` it is always bigger than `-1`.

Comment: Because for each iteration, you are simply checking if `_` exists in checkPhrase, and it does.

Comment: This is true, I feel so stupid :D
So I guess I need to find a better way to find specific characters in my string. indexOf don´t seem to fit my purpose..

Comment: Are you just wanting to count how many `_` in a string, if so -> `const countChar = str => [...str].filter(v => v === '_').length`

Comment: I would like to identify all the indexes of all the "_" in a string so I then can create an array or something. I started to get hands on with JS yesterday so I don´t have any goals with my code yet, other then getting used to it.